# Redirecting to same url after logging out

Tags: javascript, c#, http, vue.js, asp.net-core

let's say "todo-list" is a web app in which person A has complete access and person B has access to the app but not to its settings page when B tries to access the setting page its shows forbidden and navigates to the forbidden page in the app and show a signout option, but once he logged out and Person A logs in again instead of opening the home page the app is opening the forbidden page itself, which is created when B tries to access the settings page. 
             I am using Vue, Vuetify, axios, .net core 2.1 and azure AD for authorization

Comment: Are you using vue as single page application? What happens when user B loggs out? Is he redirected to the home page or to the login page? It's hard to say where  is the problem without providing a single line of code or explanation on how the app is set up

Comment: Yes, its a vue single page application, when B user logs into the unauthorised page he will be shown the forbidden page and an option to logout,so he logs out. But when A user login in again who have complete access to the app gets redirected to the forbidden page, instead of the main page, is this something to do with the session storage

Comment: So if user B was on the page `/todo/create` (just as an example), and he doesn't have permission for that. You will show the logout button on the page `/todo/create`, and when he logs out, he will be redirected to `/login` page? And then user A logs in, and it's redirected to the page `/todo/create` instead of home? And all of this is handled by `vue-router`? At no point is user redirected to backend server?

Comment: We get the role of the employee form AD when he logs in and it will be there with him as a token until he close the session, what I am saying is when user B was in page "/todo/create" which he has no access to he will be redirected to "/todo/forbidden" and shows a logout button so he can log out, after that when user A tries to login he is getting redirected to "/todo/forbidden" (hope I explained it clearly now), Thanks